# Attach SQL Server 2008 R2 on SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to attach it on a SQL Server Express 2008 instance running on Windows 2003.

I set the SQL server compatibility level on the database to SQL Server 2005 in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio before detaching.

But I can't attach this database to my SQL 2008 instance running on Windows 2003 due to a "compatibility error".

How can I get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I downgrade a SQL 2008 MDF file for use in SQL 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333145/how-do-i-downgrade-a-sql-2008-mdf-file-for-use-in-sql-2005) and many others. This is **not** a "compatibility level" error

Comment: @gbn I though it was compatibility level prblem

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Some one said me its not possible to install sql server R2 on windows server 2003 32 bit.

Comment: You need to apply SP2 to the operating system, but "some one" was wrong. Why listen to "some one" when you can check the source? Operating system support is not a secret. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't attach a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a SQL Server 2008 or 2005 instance. You can only go up, not down; you can't make your 2008 R2 database compatible with previous versions. The solution is to remove your Express instance and replace it with a 2008 R2 instance, then you will be able to attach your database...

Comment: Thank you :] Is it possible to install Sql server R2 instance on Windows server 2003 32 bit ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks and last question : windows server is not R2 nevertheless I can install sql server R2 instance on it?

Comment: Again, yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue once. I attached a 2000 DB to a 2005 instance, figured out it was the wrong instance, but now I was not able to attach it back to the 2000 instance. What I ended up doing was an export of the tables/objects from the 2005 instance and then imported it back to the 2000 instance.

Fortunately for me, the DB was very small and I did not miss any functionality during the export/import process.