# Can I attach a SQL 2008 R2 database to SQL 2008 that is not R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I attach a SQL 2008 R2 database to SQL 2008 that is not R2?

I have a database that I am detaching from SQL 2008 (not R2) and can attach this to SQL 2008 R2.

Can I then detatch the database from SQL 2008 R2 and attach it to SQL 2008 (not R2)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Attach Database to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/cannot-attach-database-to-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2) or [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5923/630). And the answer is no...

Answer (score 9):

No.

You can't do that from a higher to a lower version. R2 is considered as a new version of sql server. You can go from lower version to higher version with detach/attach.

Comment: Martin, Can we "restore" a backup database from a not r2 to a r2?

Comment: Only if the restore is done to a server with higher version of sql server installed.